# Can't setup opendns on Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, dns

It's not my first rodeo, been using Opendns for like 10 years, I just don't know why it refuses to work now on Fedora 26. My ip is in my account and my dns is as follows and I restarted the PC multiple times. I want to use it on my, pc not router.

[image]

Comment: One last question, it seems to me that cisco bought opendns, so is opendns still recommended, we all know the nsa and cisco scandal, so just want to know your opinion

Comment: Same risks as any other open DNS resolver you use and which you do not control yourself: you relinquish all rights to confidentiality as it will see all of your queries and replies, and it can also modify/filter them per its wish and it will get undetected, except if the domains use DNSSEC. You also get less performance than with a local resolver (depends on many factors)